# geonetwork meta-data harvesting: loops

Tags: geonetwork, csw

I need to setup a continental geoportal, that would be based on a series of geonetwork servers disseminated in the continent (about 6 servers).

In the geonetwork documentation, http://nationaalgeoregister.nl/geonetwork/docs/eng/users/admin/harvesting/index.html
They give an example of a hierarchical harvesting: C harvest B, B harvests A, D harvest C, B and A. According to the documentation, there is no problem due to the UUID.

In my case, the harvesting would be circular: say we have S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6,
then S1 harvests S2, S3, S4, S5, S6; S2 harvests S1, S3, S4, S5, S6, etc.
So the user can interrogate the closest geoserver, and get information for the whole continent.

Will this kind of circular approach work, or shall I fall back to a hierarchy?

Comment: Where does the metadata originally come from?

Comment: @nmtoken: sorry, I don't see the point of your question: each node has its own data, then they cross exchange them.

Comment: If all the metadata in the GeoNetwork catalogues is harvested from one or more external entities, then why not just reharvest from those entities? You won't need to reharvest all the data, only those metadata with new UUIDs or old UUIDs with newer metadata dates.